# Polymer affects react render cycler

Tags: browser, reactjs, polymer, shadow-dom

Am using polymer components in a react + flux app I am writing. I plan to use Polymer for abt 60% of the functionality. Any way Polymer can intervene with react render cycle ? (making it less performant) .

P.S. - i am using the shadow DOM

Comment: What's the reasoning behind using both Polymer AND React in the same app, given their large overlap in functionality?

Comment: bad idea. Better use this if you want the material design stuff: http://material-ui.com/#/

Comment: Am not going for material design with Polymer. Have significant logic in Polymer components, that i want to be using( can't port in snap). 

More than the choice the question here was - ' by design does something like a Polymer component' make the react render less performant or broken in some way.  Eventually all would be reactJS. but present situation is interesting for an understanding.